# Angular - 2+ ng-app directives in the same html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I need to add a controller with a function and another function to replace the { with [[ (I need to use Jekyll).

I have two ng-app:

- myApp
- invoice

Two files Javascript:

- myApp.js
- invoice.js

The following content for each file:

**myApp.JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
  });
```

**HTML myApp:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-init="qty=1;cost=2">
    <b>Invoice:</b>
    <div>
        Quantity: <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" ng-model="qty">
    </div>
    <div>
        Costs: <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" ng-model="cost">
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>
        Total:
        </b> [[qty * cost | currency]]
    </div>
</div>
```

**HTML invoice:**

```
<div ng-app="invoice1" ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
<form class="form-horizontal" id="frm_basic">   
    <b>Invoice:</b>
  <div>
    Quantity: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.qty" required >
  </div>
  <div>
    Costs: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.cost" required >
    <select ng-model="invoice.inCurr">
      <option ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">[[c]]</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>Total:</b>
    <span ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">
      [[invoice.total(c) | currency:c]]
    </span>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="invoice.pay()">Pay</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

**invoice.js:**

```
  var invoice1 = angular.module('invoice1', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    });

    invoice1.controller('InvoiceController', function() {
      this.qty = 1;
      this.cost = 2;
      this.inCurr = 'EUR';
      this.currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY'];
      this.usdToForeignRates = {
        USD: 1,
        EUR: 0.74,
        CNY: 6.09
      };

      this.total = function total(outCurr) {
        return this.convertCurrency(this.qty * this.cost, this.inCurr, outCurr);
      };
      this.convertCurrency = function convertCurrency(amount, inCurr, outCurr) {
        return amount * this.usdToForeignRates[outCurr] / this.usdToForeignRates[inCurr];
      };
      this.pay = function pay() {
        window.alert("Thanks!");
      };
    });
```

It doesn't seem work properly. It is not replacing the { with [.
[image: Error]

What is the mistake?
The error appear when I use both the html components in the page (myApp and invoice). If I disable "myApp" the second one works properly.

**RESOLVED**
**I could not have more than 1 angular instance in the same html. AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.**

Comment: Wouldn't you add controller attributes and functions to the $scope rather than this?

Comment: It may be a just a typo, but you say you want to use `[` while you are asking the `$interpolateProvider` to use `[[` as delimiter.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say [[ but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider) you have to use `invoic1.config(....`

The example works fine - provide a plunker with your code so we can help you.

```js
  var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('App', []);

  customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
  });


  customInterpolationApp.controller('DemoController', function() {
      this.label = "This binding is brought you by // interpolation symbols.";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
    //demo.label//
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working. I added the code in the original post.